# Automating multiple page breaks in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, macros

I have a long document which contains likes like this:

**"21-1 Population Genetics  Author: John Smith"**

I would like to introduce a page break in front of every line that contains `"Author: "`, and the break has to be before the line, not after, so that the chapter name ends up on the next page.

Given the size of the document, it is inconvenient to do it manually. Any suggestions how I would automate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this without programming using Word's find and replace with wildcards. In the *Find and Replace* dialog click on *More* and check the *Use wildcards* option. Then enter

- `(^13)([0-9]@-[0-9]@*Author:)` as the *Find what* text, and
- `\1^m\2` as the *Replace with* text.

[image]

Here is a breakdown of what the find and replace patterns do:

- the find text searches for

  - a paragraph mark (`^13`),
  - followed by 1 or more digits (`[0-9]@`)
  - followed by a hyphen (`-`)
  - followed by 1 or more digits (`[0-9]@`)
  - followed by any characters
  - followed by the text `Author:`
- using parenthesis, the find pattern captures the found text in two pieces, splitting after the paragraph mark
- the replace pattern inserts

  - the first capture (i.e. the found paragraph mark, `\1`),
  - a manual page break (`^m`)
  - the remaining text until "Author:" (`\2`)

If you want to do the same via a macro, its easiest to use Word's macro recorder.